# Python GPIO LED no current on PIN

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio

first of all I have read a lot of threads here about this topic and I can't find my mistake.
It is very easy I want to make a LED blink via GPIO with Python. My code is this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

while(1):
        GPIO.output(12,True)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(12,False)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I also tried this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

while(1):
        GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(12,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
```

And here is my wiring:

[image]

The LED is working, I tried it with a battery. (3V) But it is not blinking when I call my script like this:

```
sudo python an.py
```

Comment: Do you have a micrometer or similar you can use to check the GPIO pins output too? (I'm surprised you don't need a resistor in there but my electronics is rusty.)

Comment: i tired with resistor and without. i check with a multimeter, gpio doenst work

Comment: From your picture, it looks like you are connected to the **6-th** pin from the right, which is **Ground**. Doublecheck the pin layout, GPIO 12 is **5-th** pin from the right.

Comment: tried it on the 5th pin, doesnt work and my multimeter say 1.5V , but thank you for the help